# Flask: make POST requests to development server

Tags: python, http, flask, post, http-post

I can run a Flask app/API on my local machine using `flask run` on the command line. This will set up a local server (for me, at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`), and run the app at that address.

Having done this, I can make GET requests to my app just by visiting `http://127.0.0.1:5000/<route>` in my browser. **How can I make a POST request to the app?** I also have parameters I want to include in the body of the POST request.

Comment: you can't make POST using URL in browser. It needs HTML page which has `<form method="POST">` - so your server would have send this page to you. Instead of browser you can use modules like `urllib` or `requests` which can run `requests.post(...)`. Some people use GUI tools like [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to test pages - and it can also send `POST`. You may also try to use console programs like `curl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make request `POST` using `URL` in browser. It needs `HTML` page which has

```
<form method="POST">

</form>
```

so your server would have send this page to you.

---

Instead of browser you can use Python modules like `urllib` or simpler `requests` which can run `.get()`, `.post(...)`, etc.

In example I use https://httpbin.org/post because it sends back all what yout get - headers, post data, cookies, etc. so you can see what you send.

```py
import requests

#url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'

# POST/form data
payload = {
    'search': 'hello world',
}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

print(r.text)
```

Result:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "search": "hello world"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Content-Length": "18", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.26.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61687ab9-7bae70cf5bfdcbb75524b71b"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "83.11.118.179", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

---

Some people use `GUI` tools like [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to test pages - and it can also send requests POST/GET/DELETE/OPTION/etc.

[image]

---

You may also try to use console programs like [curl](https://curl.se/)

```
curl https://httpbin.org/post -X POST -d "search=hello world"
```

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "search": "hello world"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "18", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.68.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61687da3-5eaaa4ff6419c36639a2cc5d"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "83.11.118.179", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

---

**BTW:**

Some API uses [curl](https://curl.se/) in documentation as example to show how to use API.

There is page https://curl.trillworks.com which can convert from `curl` to Python `requests` (but sometimes has problem to do it correctly)